# Generate an Array of Random Integers in which Every Element is Different from its Successor and Predecessor in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to write an alternative version of the Random().nextInt() method that doesn't generate the same number two times in a row. I searched on StackOverflow but, curiously, the methods I found managed to work only when the range of the random values was sufficiently great (greater than 4 if I'm not being wrong).

To be more specific, I'm trying to generate an int[] of 6 random integers k (0 <= k <= 3) in which every element is different both from its successor and predecessor.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution: after generating the next random number, compare it to the previous one. If they are the same, discard the last one and generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quick pseudocode version for you

1. Generate a random number
2. Compares that number with the previous number.
3. If it is the same then repeat steps 1 and 2.
4. If it is different store the number.
5. return the number

Note: be sure to not have a range of numbers with only one integer inside or else you might get stuck in a loop.

There is certainly a better/different way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about what I'd do in Python. Something like based on the range you want the ints to be in e.g. 1.100 create an arraylist of those integers and then access the list at random and pop/remove the element from the list. Or create a static list of random numbers then cast to a set to remove duplicates, then wire the nextInt() up to the set.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> MyRandom(int size, int k)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        array.add(new Random().nextInt(k));
        while (array.size() <= size)
        {
            int val = new Random().nextInt(k);
            if (array.get(array.size() - 1) != val && (!(val == 1 && array.get(array.size() - 1) == 0)) && 
                    (!(val == 0 && array.get(array.size() - 1) == 1))) array.add(val);
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int last = rand.nextInt(3);
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
last = (last +1 + rand.nextInt(2)) % 4
array.add(last)
}
```

Advantage: you really only generate O(k) values...